# MacBookPro10,1 can't adjust backlight In Ubuntu, have tried everything

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, brightness, macbook-pro, backlight

This is my last ditch attempt to get backlight controls working in Ubuntu 16.0.4 on my MacBook Pro 10,1 (Retina, Mid-2012) with an NVIDIA GeForce GT 650M. I'm using the NVIDIA driver version 384.111.

I have looked at a bunch of questions like this and tried every answer I could find, but nothing has worked for me. So far I have tried:

1. adding

   ```
   setpci -v -H1 -s 00:01.00 BRIDGE_CONTROL=0
   ```

   to `/etc/rc.local`
2. including

   ```
   Option "RegistryDwords" "EnableBrightnessControl=1"
   ```

   in the `Device` Section of `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`
3. changing

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
   ```

   to

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor"
   ```

   in `/etc/default/grub` and then running `sudo update-grub`
4. using `xbacklight`, which just has no effect
5. this thing that I didn't really understand: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=105051#c37

One thing I have noticed is that the directory `/sys/class/backlight` is empty. I'm thinking that may be part of the problem, but I don't understand what to do with that information.

Thanks in advance for any help you can offer!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who finds this, I found a solution by accident when I booted using an old kernel (4.4.0-116-generic). Suddenly the backlight worked!